# Сортировать массив строк по убыванию согласных букв с помощью qsort

Tags: c, строки, qsort

Как с помощью qsort сортировать строки по убыванию согласных букв

Comment: Задав правильный компаратор :)

Comment: Сделайте вспомогательный массив структур, содержащих указатель на строку и количество согласных в ней и *отсортируйте его* (конечно, правильный компаратор все равно нужен)

Comment: @avp Просто интереса ради - вы поняли, что требуется в задаче? я, откровенно признаюсь, не очень...

Comment: @Harry, мне кажется, что понял. Хотя, ... только что осознал, что убывание согласных может быть вовсе не связано с их количеством в строке. Да уж, пусть автор объяснит поточнее -- у строки ключ сортировки это строка согласных (пишем вариант strcmp), их количество или что-то еще...

Comment: Убывание согласных букв... Что-то плакать хочется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Список гласных букв
// Кирилицу добавите сами
char vowel_list[] = "AEIOUaeiou";

// Функция, которая копирует только согласные буквы
// Возвращает длину получившейся строки
int consonant_copy(char *dest, char  *src) {
    size_t len_s, len_d;
    int j;

    len_s = strlen(src) + 1; 
    // Выполняем перенос символов
    len_d = 0;
    for (j=0; j<len_s; j++) {
        if ( index(vowel_list, src[j]) == 0) {
            // Нет в списке гласных
            dest[len_d] = src[j];
            len_d++;
        }
    }
    dest[len_d] ='\0';

    return ++len_d;
}

// Функция сравнения только по согласным буквам
// Как обычно, возвращает -1, 0 и 1 по результату сравнения
// Случай строк, полностью состоящих из гласных, отдельно не рассматривается.
int consonant_compare(const void *str1, const void *str2) {
    int rc;
    char *w1, *w2;
    size_t len;

    // Получаем копии строк без согласных
    len = strlen((char *)str1) + 1;
    w1 =  (char *)malloc(len);
    rc = consonant_copy(w1, (char *)str1);
    len = strlen((char *)str2) + 1;
    w2 =  (char *)malloc(len);
    rc = consonant_copy(w2, (char *)str2);

    // Выполняем сравнение
    rc = strcmp(w1, w2);

    // Освобождаем память
    free(w1);
    free(w2);

    return rc;
}

// Тестовая программа для проверки этих функций
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int j;
    void *ptr;

    // Тестовые данные
    char *test_data[10] = {
        "qwerty",
        "wertyu",
        "ertyui",
        "rtyuio",
        "tyuiop",
        "zxcvbo",
        "zxcvon",
        "zxcobn",
        "zxovbn",
        "zocvbn",
    };

    // Сортируем, предварительно разместив данные в куче
    ptr = malloc(70);
    memcpy(ptr, (void *)test_data[0], 70 );
    qsort(ptr, 10, 7, consonant_compare);

    // Печатаем результат
    for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", (char *)ptr+7*j);
    }

}
```

Comment: Первое замечание: сортируемые данные пришлось перенести в "кучу", так в область констант запись невозможна.

Comment: Второе замечание: Размер элемента массива задан 7, а не 6, так как там есть ещё ноль-терминатор.